# ArabTeX output not correct

Tags: arabtex

I am trying to force LaTeX to output the word ﺍﻨﺗﺑﻪ, however the output for the minimal working example provided below is

[image: incorrect arabic output]

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}
\setcode{utf8}
\setarab
Arabic \<ﺍﻨﺗﺑﻪ> within latin.

\end{document}
```

I'm using TeXWorks 0.6.1 with MikTeX 2.9 64-bit under Windows 10.

I can get XeLaTeX to output the proper word, however my main document is in LaTeX, so a solution using XeLaTeX is not particularly useful due to incompatible packages, unless there is an easy way in which I can embed XeLaTeX within LaTeX.

Please also note that I'm not a speaker of Arabic.

Comment: There aren't so many incompatible packages Maybe they could be replaced  with compatible ones?

Comment: There is a problem with the way you write that arabic word. The correct way is انتبه.

Comment: Maybe you need to adjust your editor font encoding to utf8

Comment: @SalimBou Yes, the editor is set to utf8 encoding, thanks.

Comment: @CroCo, thanks. The original author wrote it like that in an MS Word document (which I'm converting for her into LaTeX), I just copy-pasted it into a utf8-capable editor. Is it possible to tell from this example alone if this is a spelling issue, or a copy-paste issue?

Comment: My first thought was that you've copied and pasted it from somewhere. Moreover, it is not a correct-spelled word. Pay attention to the second letter (i.e. noon). There is a little line before it. This little curved line has no meaning. Compare mine with yours to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}
\setcode{utf8}
Arabic \<انتبه> within latin.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works from my end as well, thank you.